# How to unit test Quorum projects?

Tags: testrpc, testing, quorum

I'd like to build unit tests for a Quorum project including the Quorum specific part that is the privateFor attribute in the transactions. Is there a tool like testrpc specific to Quorum ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a Quorum chain up and running using the [7 Nodes Example](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples). Then, you can actually use Truffle to compose and run tests in the same way you would for Ethereum with testrpc. `truffle.js` should be modified

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 22001, // This is your second node, 22002 for second, etc.
      network_id: "*", 
      gasPrice: 0,
      gas: 4500000
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a tutorial with more details: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains.

Comment: thanks I'm aware of how to create a real quorum chain, but that would make for a rather impractical and slow unit tests setup (how do you reset the blockchain state between tests for example ?). I was thinking of something as practical and lightweight as testrpc

Comment: With Truffle, you can use `truffle migrate --reset` so that each migration is fresh, and for tests, new contracts are launched each time you run and if you use a `beforeEach()` hook in your tests then you are looking at different contract instances each test - this is how working with testrpc works as well, or else you'd need to restart testrpc each time you wanted to test.

Comment: testrpc takes blockchain state snapshots, restores those outside mocha "contract" calls and allows to restore those manually as well. you can also advance the block timestamps ...

Comment: Except for the ability to advance block timestamps, because you're right - I don't think that's achievable, but it'd be similar to testing with Ropsten or Rinkeby. You're still able to interact with the contract in the `truffle console` the same as an Ethereum network, so you're receiving the same type of Truffle artifacts that you'd need for testing results